# In Spring-Data-JPA CrudRepository, what plays for "C"?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, crud

CRUD stands for [create, read, update, and delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

So, "C" stands for "create".

What method in [`CrudRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) plays for "C" then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [CrudRepository#save](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) which can update an existing entity (merge) or persist a newly created one.